# Running a generator on the back of a flatbed - Safety Concerns

Tags: safety, generator, health-and-safety, audio

Fourth of July is coming up, and we're doing music for the parade off a 1990's Dodge flat-bed truck.

**Equipment**

1. Electric drum kit... the brain is the only electronic (see below)[image]
2. PA system (2000 watts)
3. Generator (3500 watts) (Gas powered) - if you need exact model I can get it

**I have safety concerns.**

1. The diesel truck fumes on top of the output from the generator might be a lot of carbon monoxide. I can only sit about 5 or 6 feet away from the generator at most. The best I can do is point it off the back. We're driving slow, maybe even stopped at times...
2. Power requirements. Is watts all I have to care about? I'm going to have in ear monitors hooked up to this system. I don't want to get shocked to death because it spikes or damage equipment because it can't handle it. How do I test how much power this system is using?

   - People have mentioned *purifying* the "dirty power" from the generator. Not sure what that means?

This may not be worth it, which is a bummer. I'd like to do it if I can safely.

Comment: Are the in-ear monitors wireless? Is the genny diesel or gas?  Is it a quality brand like Honda or a cheap PoJ?

Comment: Is it possible to put the generator on a towed trailer?

Comment: Could the truck itself provide the power? Granted 2 kW may be stretching it especially for an older truck.

Comment: @Harper Gen Brand: Champion https://www.amazon.com/Champion-Power-Equipment-46596-Generator/dp/B009E26LL2. I believe this one is gas. Is Champion quality? I don't know

Comment: @mikes That is a good idea. it probably is possible

Comment: @ratchetfreak I'm not sure if I understand. How do I get the truck to provide a plug-able outlet?

Comment: @KolobCanyon 12VDC to main inverter or change the power supply of the drums and PA (which steps down from mains to a lower DC voltage) to take the 12V directly

Comment: That would be the safest way if that can happen.  That keeps mains power entirely away from the performers.

Comment: @ratchetfreak So, plug a converter into the cigarette lighter on the truck route the wire through the window, and provide power to the drums? Probably wouldn't be enough for the PA I would imagine? Sorry, I don't fully understand what a 12VDC main inverter is doing or how I plug it in

Comment: @KolobCanyon yeah or add an extra generator to the engine for more power.

Comment: Diesel generator.  Carbon monoxide goes away.  Bonus points, fuel both with B100 and the particulate becomes nontoxic and your truck smells like french fries.

Comment: I've been thinking of using a mixture of your suggestions. **So far:** put the generator and PA on a trailer - connect the PA to the generator. Put the drum kit on the flatbed - connect to the cigarette lighter in the car. Buy a wireless quarter inch cable and push the output from the drums to the PA wireless. Seems safe to me? I won't even be connected to the generator system if I do that